# How to find out what handler is registered to a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I would like to be able to programatically find out what handler is registered to a particular shortcode. I want to be able to find this so I can save it, change it, perform a do_shortcode, then change it back to what it was originally.

I understand WordPress has a gobal variable $wp_filter for registered filters... Is there and equivalent for shortcodes?

Answer (score 1):

The below WordPress snippet will give you a list of all the WordPress shortcodes you have available on your blog.

```
<?php
        global $shortcode_tags;
        echo '<pre>'; 
        print_r($shortcode_tags); 
        echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Also check the **[`Codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)** for more information about `shortcodes`

Comment: Temporarily you can append this to the bottom of your /index.php to ensure all of WP has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Found it $shortcode_tags

If you do printer( $shortcode_tags ) you will get a listing of registered tags